# Anchor in arbitrary position with sphinx/reStructuredText?

Tags: python-sphinx

Is it possible to add an anchor (link target, to which I can refer with `:ref:`) at an arbitrary position in the text? I have a situation like this:

```
Some text

.. class:: mylist

**Term 1**
  Definition

*Term 2*
  Definition

:customrole:`Term 3` extra
  Definition
```

And I'd like to add a link to, say `Term 2`. I cannot simply add `.. _target:` before the block, because that breaks the list in two, and the second part does not get the `mylist` class (is this intentional or could it be a bug?). I could write this:

```
*Term 2*
  .. _target:

  Definition
```

but then the target is the definition paragraph, not the `Term 2` element itself.

Applying an inline role to `Term 2` is not simple either, because then there's the problem of nested formatting (I've used different styles for each terms to show that there could be a variety of situations I'd need this for). Maybe if I could apply an inline role to some empty text...

Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Sphinx anchor on arbitrary line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30822880/python-sphinx-anchor-on-arbitrary-line)

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a similar question here, hopefully this solves your problem:

[Python Sphinx anchor on arbitrary line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30822880/python-sphinx-anchor-on-arbitrary-line/30989921#30989921)

In summary, you can use the `ref` role: http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#role-ref

Specifically read the 2nd bullet point which addresses what happens if the reference is not placed before a title.

Comment: My problem is not writing the reference, but placing the anchor, which either breaks the list or puts the anchor in the description, not the item itself. The `:term:` solution only works for glossaries, apparently (or how would I use it in my example?)

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I know is to place your definition list into a [glossary directive](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-glossary)
and refer its terms with the [term role](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-term) ...

```
Some text

.. glossary::

  Term 1
    Definition

  Term 2
    Definition

A link to :term:`Term 1` or :term:`Term 2`
```