# Python Sphinx anchor on arbitrary line

Tags: python, anchor, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

How can I set an anchor reference at an arbitrary line in ReST using Sphinx?

To be more clear, here is an example:

```
A title with an anchor
----------------------

some stuff
```

this will create a heading `A title with an anchor` and add an extra *on-hover* `¶` character at the end of the line, which will be an anchor reference to that line/heading.

Now in the following case...

```
``some arbitrary line``
    this is actually a definition
```

...I want to have an anchor for `some arbitrary line`, the same way as for the heading.

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/26003717/407651

Comment: Yes, exactly the same, but again, no answers :(

Comment: @bagrat I added an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52576252/300130

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with a role called `ref`:
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-ref

Specifically read the 2nd bullet point which addresses what happens if the reference is not placed before a title.

For example, in a file called `example.rst` this is how you would use:

```
.. _arbitrary-anchor:

Some Arbitrary Line
    This is actually a definition
```

The label "arbitrary-anchor" has to be unique through out the document. To reference this anchor somewhere in the document, you would do something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum :ref:`here is the anchor link <arbitrary-anchor>` dolor sit amet
```

Unfortunately, this anchor will not show up when you **hover** over the referenced line, but you should be able to access it using an explicit link to `http://example.com/example.html#arbitrary-anchor`

---

Since you mention **definitions** - it is also worth noting that there is a role called `term` which lets you reference a definition in the glossary.

For an example of how to use this, see: http://sphinx-doc.org/glossary.html#term-role

and how this is referenced in the 3rd paragraph of:
http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#domains

---

Lastly, if you need to insert an anchor in the middle of a paragraph, one way to do it is by creating an explicit `<a id=#sample>inline anchor</a>` by using a `raw role`:
http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#raw

---

**EDIT:**

There is one more option. This will create an anchor and the hover effect.

```
.. rst:role:: Sample rst role

    This is a sample definition which links back to its anchor :rst:role:`Sample rst role`
```

This is a funny looking directive that I've been using for a while now. I found it when I was looking at the source of this page:

http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#inline-markup

http://sphinx-doc.org/_sources/markup/inline.txt

*The text looks like this when you hover:*
[image]

*The text looks like this after you click on the link:*
[image]

This option is less that ideal because it displays the `:` to the left and right of the definition. But it is nice because it creates an anchor and hover on something that's not a title (so it doesn't show up in the TOC as well, which is exactly what I wanted)

Comment: that syntax accomplishes what you describe, but it doesn't *mean* what you describe. The meaning of that sytax is "document an rst text role". Which is not what you are doing. That's why the two colons are there.