# How to define the name of a reference, without a proceeding title? (reStructuredText)

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In reStructuredText, its common to use references to link [arbitrary locations in a document.](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#cross-referencing-arbitrary-locations)

When there is no title, a caption needs to be given with the reference. eg:

```
Some text in a paragraph.

.. _my-reference:

Some more text.

Link to :ref:`My Reference <my-reference>` more text.
another link to :ref:`My Reference <my-reference>`.
```

Is there a way to have the caption text be stored once at the reference location to avoid a lot of repetition on every link?

non-functional example:

```
Some text in a paragraph.

.. _my-reference: My Reference

Some more text.

Link to :ref:`my-reference` more text.
another link to :ref:`my-reference`.
```

I'm linking to definitions in long definition lists, so adding titles in the middle isn't an option.

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/26003717/407651

Comment: Its similar but Im asking about how to avoid having to explicitly include the caption in every reference.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2025